# Why is the background black?

Tags: java, graphics

The background worked before I added the paint method, I assume the paint method overrides the setBackground and setForeground methods in run, but I'm not sure how I can fix this problem.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Afterworld extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
        Afterworld game = new Afterworld();
        game.run(dm);
    }

    public void run(DisplayMode dm){
        setBackground(Color.PINK);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));

        Screen screen = new Screen();
        try{
            screen.setFullScreen(dm, this);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }catch(Exception ex){}
        }finally{
            screen.restoreScreen();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("test", 200, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is Screen class here?

Comment: Ouch. You're sleeping in the EDT.

Comment: I'm about 84% sure `Thread.sleep()` is a terrible idea here.  It looks like you're tying up the thread that otherwise would be updating your UI.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud change your `paint` method for:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString("test", 200, 200);
}
```

The call to `super.paint(g);` executes whatever code is in the superclass. That is exactly the code that painted the background before you added the `paint` method.

You can learn more about accessing superclass' members at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: What is `parent`? Do you mean `super`.

Comment: Excuseme, it was `super`, not  `parent`. I was mixing languages

Comment: @codeNinja: Definitely not `this`.  That'd cause infinite recursion.

Comment: Oops, didn't think about that long enough.

Comment: There we go. Stackoverflow doesn't believe that you edited it though, so I can't remove the downvote. You need to edit it again, possibly explaining why `super.paint(g)` should be added.

Comment: Ok. I thing it is better now.